# how to delete contact by number telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

**Imports:**

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact
from telethon import functions, types
```

**Code:**

```
phone_number = "some_friend_phone_no"
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=phone_number, first_name="first", last_name="last") #enter phone number with settings
contacts = client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest([contact])) #import that number to contacts
if len(contacts.users) > 0: #if user exists on telegram
    username = contacts.users[0].username #then insert user value into username variable
    if username is not None: #if username is not empty
        client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(id=[username])) #then DELETE that contact
```

That code first add an `phone_number` to our contacts list and after we can easily get their username.

After we delete that contact as we just needed their username.

But some users don't have set username so we get username as `None`.

Now how to remove that contact ?
Currently I use `client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(id=[username]))`, which will fail if username is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/delete_contacts.html), you can make an `InputUser` and then give it to `DeleteContactRequest`.

As you already have the user, you can:

```
client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(id=[contacts.users[0]]))
```

Comment: Very simple and straight forward answer. Code has worked. Thanks so much.